# How do I make the brackets [ ] more dark for mathematical purpose?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

When a work involves the brackets [ ] for mathematical purpose, say closed intervals [*a*, *b*], I always feel that, even with Amsart, the brackets [ ] are not that clear in output. The brackets just seem not dark enough. I wonder if there is any way to "fix" this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\interval}[1]{\boldsymbol{[}#1\boldsymbol{]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 [a,b] \quad \text{versus} \quad \interval{a,b}
 \end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I found not the command "\boldsymbol"! Right on.

Comment: You're welcome.  Also look into the `bm` package.

Comment: What if, for example, one wants to write the interval `[\frac{2}{3},b]`?

Comment: The question was how to make brackets bold.   But in general it's better to use the bracket pairing commands in mathtools for bracketing operations.